# Does picking feats from a multiclass archetype work the same way as if they were from the "Other" section?

Tags: feats, pathfinder-2e, multi-classing, archetype

[In the rules](https://2e.aonprd.com/Archetypes.aspx), archetypes are divided in two groups. **Multiclass Archetypes** and **Other Archetypes**.

If I'm not mistake, in the first group, in order to pick up the archetype (dedication feat) you have to give up a class feat. After that, you need to give up a class feat to pick a feat from that archetype (unless that feat has the skill trait, in which case you can give up a skill feat).

Does it work the same way for the other archetypes, like ghost or geomancer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Yes

All archetypes work the same way. The general rules for [archetypes](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=167) include these lines: (emphasis mine)

> Applying an archetype requires you to select archetype feats **instead of class feats**. Start by finding the archetype that best fits your character concept, and select the archetype’s dedication feat **using one of your class feat choices**. Once you have the dedication feat, you can select any feat from that archetype **in place of a class feat** as long as you meet its prerequisites.

So yes, you take one of these feats instead of a class feat, except when the feat has the skill trait, as you write in the question.

> Occasionally, an archetype feat works like a skill feat instead of a class feat. These archetype feats have the skill trait, and you select them **in place of a skill feat**

Comment: FWIW, the distinction between multiclass archetypes and other archetypes rarely comes up - the only instance I can think of is [Multitalented](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=77).